# Can I use the symbol "F" ( falsum) as an equivalent of " x belongs to the null set" to prove basic set theoretical laws? Is this standard practice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

As a little exercice in logic, I'm trying to prove :

If A is included in B, then the intersection  of A and of Comp(B) is equal to the null set.

Could I proceed as follows? ( Do I use correctly the constant Falsum?)

Lets admit that A is included in B.

Goal : a double inclusion, and thus, a bi-implication.

(1) ( ---> )

Suppose, for conditional proof, that :  x belongs to A Inter Comp(B).

We have:  x belongs both to A and to Comp(B), so x does not belong to B.

But at the same time ( by hypothesis), if x belongs to A, x belongs to B ( A being included in B).  And x belongs to A ( since it belongs to A Inter Comp(B) ). So x belongs to B.

**Our hypothseis implies F ( falsum) which is equivalent to " x belongs to the null set"**.

By conditional proof , we have shown that : for all x, if x belongs to A Inter Comp(B), then x belongs to the null set; or, in other words, that : A Inter Comp(B) is included in the null set.

(2) (<--- )

Suppose for conditional proof that : x belongs to the null set.

This supposition is **equivalent to : F ( Falsum).**

But **F ( Falsum) implies any proposition**, in particular " x belongs to A Inter Comp(B) ".

So, for all x, if x belongs to the null set, then x belongs to A Inter Comp(B), which means that the null set is included in A Inter Comp(B).

Conclusion : If A is included in B,  the sets " A Inter Comp(B)" and the null set are included in each other, which means that they are equal.

Comment: *Falsum* ($\bot$) is a "logical constant" that is Always False. Thus, every contradiction $p \land \lnot p$ works in the same way. What you are doing is : assume $P$ and derive a contradiction : $\bot$. Falsum is equivalent to the contradiction $P \land \lnot P$ and not to $\lnot P$.

Comment: Obviously, having derived $\bot$ from $P$, you are allowed to conclude with $\lnot P$ (this is a simple rule of inference). In your case, $P$ is $x \in A \cap B^C$ and thus you have derived : $x \notin A \cap B^C$. Then you "generalize" it to conclude with $\forall x (x \notin A \cap B^C)$.

Comment: Obviously, in the context of set theory, $x \in \emptyset$ **is** always false, due to the axiom stating that $\forall x \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$.

Comment: @ Mauro Allegranza . Thanks.